# Android app how to detect which component doing web requests?

Tags: java, android

I have android application which is using multiple libraries (built into app: e.g. android support v7, barcode zxing, google play, and couple other less known).

Trying to resolve some functional issues, I detected that app periodically is doing web https requests to strange ec2.x.amazonaws.com addreses which are not mine servers at all.

Addresses are:

```
ec2.174-129-33-55.compute-1.amazonaws.com, 
ec2.107-21-232-174.compute-1.amazonaws.com, 
ec2.50-17-229-89.compute-1.amazonaws.com, 
ec2.54-225-166-66.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

In a quite large java code I cannot find explicit calls to these addresses.
So, question is, how to detect which component in my app is doing these requests?
I'm using android app "Network Log" to trace traffic.

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was trying to use Stetho but no luck huking into tracing web requests. Was able to get chrome view but no info.
But I found what is doing requests: it's a Crashlytics crash monitoring service - I discovered this by trying to query ip in browser and checked ssl certificate info...

Answer (score 1):

You might see if [stetho](https://github.com/facebook/stetho) picks it up.

Comment: But Stetho is only for hybrid apps? i.e. for apps using webkit. Or am I wrong?

Comment: No Stetho is for native apps. I use it in all of mine. It's awesome.